# A service oriented company with deadlines on go live what approach need to be taken?

Tags: manual-testing, test-planning, test-strategy, service, testing-strategies

I am working now in a service oriented company where client already specifies about go live date.

Developer estimate their timeline and as a tester i also provide my timeline. Since go live cannot change, developer may work 24/7 and some how complete 1-2 days before go live and PM will ask for testing.. (websites which are mobile friendly/responsive etc).

what approach can be taken in this tight schedule?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk-based_testing

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on quite many parameters, such as:

- how long are you running the project?
- how flexible the client is?
- what is the company's management approach?
- how good is the collaboration with the developers?

The scenario you described used to occur at small companies, lack or poor management, trying to deliver as many projects as soon as possible, without concerning about the quality.

What you can do, based on my opinion, in short term is to document every risk you see. You test the website in one day, do your best, but document every impediment you find (email, jira, whichever tracking tool) and let the client know about the risk. It will be their responsibility if they don't postpone the release. Your job is to find the critical points of the application.

On long term you should try to convince the client/management to be a little bit more organized, time box the testing too, not only the development. I would suggest to use scrum because it allows many releases and it's more structured, however I don't think agile is applicable for every software development case.

Comment: Yes, even management knows.. they also struggle in this scenario. We cannot say no to client as they provide revenue. They know qa juz go through 1 browser (no test plan, no test case).. just exploitary testing. Can we only define its exploitary testing, if so how much coverage we need to tel and how much leakage we need to expect etc.

Comment: "used to occur at small companies".  I've seen it more at large companies and i've seen it happen more now than in the past.  However, like you my evidence is circumstantial and bassed on my own experience

Answer (score 0):

I have few friends working in same situation in software testing services company. Few approaches you should follow:
1) Try to report critical issues ASAP and shoot an email to all stakeholders

- Issue:
- Features Impacted
- How much you are blocked? Are you able to further test or completely blocked on feature.

Continue your testing and ensure that sanity works fine - all features are working fine on top.

You can create an feature checklist in advance that you will execute when you get the QA Ready build.

Confirm from your management or Product owner which browsers or platforms are highest priority so you are testing on P1 browser/configuration.

At the end of day write an email (kind of GO NO GO report) mentioning

- Testing Start Time:
- Configuration/Browsers you have tested
- Feature checklist results that you have executed
- Table for all the defects Reported (just write self descriptive one liner defect to save time)
- Clearly mention is the Build worth releasing or not.
- Pending Testing Areas
- Risk associated with releasing the product

Everyone fears releasing a poor quality product, you have done your best and share your testing results and concerns. Its upto management to decide.